# How do i count words in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I try to count words in a string in prolog. Like "No, I am definitely not a pie!"
To give me the number 7 and next example "w0w such t3xt... to give number 5.
I had thougt about subtract that are a library function and only get back white-characters. But the problem then is No   way will give back 5 and not two words.
I thought about

```
filter([],L).
filter([X,Y|XS],[Y|XS]):-  X = ' ',Y = ' ',L = [Y|XS], filter([Y|XS],L).
filter([X|XS],L):- filter(Xs,L).
```

That will remove white spaces and get back No way but it dosent work anbody have a tip.

Comment: Could you please close `"<--- the quotes delimiting the strings --->"`, and emphasize `keywords` like `subtract` by enclosing them into back-ticks? Currently, I don't understand you question.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in Prolog are lists of character codes not of atoms, what explains why tests like `X=' '` fail. See what is the result of executing

```
write("ab cd"), nl.
```

in your Prolog system.

You have errors in your 3 clauses:

1. What to do you expect the first clause to return in the last argument?
   `L` is, as any other variable in a Prolog program, a variable that is local to the clause it appears in, never a global variable.
2. The second clause unifies `L` with a list and you use it as second argument of the recursive call: do you expect the recursive call to change the value of `L`? This will never be the case: in Prolog there is no assignment of variables, changes are made by building terms and unifying them with **new** variables.
3. What happens to `X` in your third clause???